# how to host a zip file and download it using asp.net C#?

Tags: asp.net, download, zip

I have a zip file ready at disposal and I want to host it on my page and provide download link to it. can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can  save file on your  directory and provide your website link with that file like

Website URL:  http://xdomain.com/yourpage.aspx

Save file using  server.map  path with directory Files in  http://xdomain.com/Files/zipfile.zip

Provide this link to download as http://xdomain.com/Files/zipfile.zip